# References for learning about online random forests

Tags: machine-learning, references, random-forest, algorithms, online-algorithms

I am new to concepts of random forest. Can someone provide relevant sites where I could get learn more about using random forests to learn incoming data like an online algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand why this is off-topic. Asking for references is on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

The following papers present various concepts about online random forests.

- [Mondrian Forests: Efficient Online Random Forests](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5234-mondrian-forests-efficient-online-random-forests.pdf) contains material about the random forest.
- [The Mondrian Process](http://danroy.org/papers/RoyTeh-NIPS-2009.pdf) contains more theoretical background about the underlying process.

And there are some implementations available on github :

- **Python**, this implementation corresponds to the papers https://github.com/balajiln/mondrianforest
- **C++** this one is based on other publications https://github.com/amirsaffari/online-random-forests